# Strings as keys of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

When using strings as keys of an array, `console` is showing that the array  without these declared values and while iterating by this values where keys are string aren't displayed? , although i can get value of them.

```
>> var arr = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ];
   undefined

>> arr["something"] = "aught";
   "aught"

>> arr
   [0, 1, 2, 3]

>> arr["something"]
   "aught"

>> for( var i = arr.length; i--; console.log( arr[ i ] ) );
   3
   2
   1
   0
```

I understand that arrays are objects which has implemented some kind of 'enumerate' interface in JavaScript's engine.

Most interesting is that interpreter **isn't throwing either warning or error**, so I spent some time of searching for where data could be lost.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

In javascript there are 2 type of arrays: standard arrays and associative arrays

- `[ ]` - standard array - 0 based integer indexes only
- `{ }` - associative array - javascript objects where keys can be any strings

So when you define:

```
var arr = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ];
```

you are defining a standard array where indexes can only be integers. When you do `arr["something"]` since `something` (which is what you use as index) is not an integer you are basically defining a property to the `arr` object (everything is object in javascript). But you are not adding an element to the standard array.

Comment: @abuduba, because there is nothing wrong :-) Your code is perfectly valid javascript. It's ambiguous to the reader since you are mixing the 2 type of arrays but it is valid. Why would you want the interpreter to indicate that something is wrong when there is nothing wrong.

Comment: This is mostly a terminology issue, but javascript does NOT generally call `{}` an associative array.  They call it an object that has properties.  Don't most people agree that it's best not to confuse things by calling a javascript object an associative array?

Comment: Note: If you try to use ``defineProperty`` on the array like ``Object.defineProperty.call(arr,'something','aught');`` it will throw an error.

Comment: You`re right.  Key something is property of object instead index of array => `arr.something`. Maybe I'am too long without sleep .. I forgot that. Thanks
@David - Nice, i did`nt know about it

Comment: It's really strange because in console, `var a = []; a['test'] = ""; a;` displays `['test': ""]` therefore `a.length` is empty as expected. Also it's strange because if we add something like this `a[0] = 0;` both keys 'o' and 'test' has a property of 'a', It's hard to understand!

Answer (score 16):

> `for( var i = arr.length; i--; console.log( arr[ i ] ) );`

This will only give you the numeric indices, of course, but you can still loop over both numeric indices **and** string keys of your array like this:

```
for (var x in arr) {
    console.log(x + ": " + arr[x]);
}
/* (console output):
     0: 0
     1: 1
     2: 2
     3: 3
     something: aught
*/
```

Comment: so, lets add this `Array.prototype.somethingCool = "not really";`  and then run your for-in-loop !!