# Sorting multidimensional array jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
var klas4 = [];

klas4[2] = [];
klas4[2]["hour"] = 1;
klas4[2]["teacher"] = "JAG";
klas4[2]["group"] = "V4A";
klas4[2]["subject"] = "IN";
klas4[2]["classroom"] = "B111";

klas4[0] = [];
klas4[0]["hour"] = 6;
klas4[0]["teacher"] = "JAG";
klas4[0]["group"] = "V4B";
klas4[0]["subject"] = "IN";
klas4[0]["classroom"] = "B111";

klas4[1] = [];
klas4[1]["hour"] = 4;
klas4[1]["teacher"] = "NAG";
klas4[1]["group"] = "V4A";
klas4[1]["subject"] = "NA";
klas4[1]["classroom"] = "B309";
```

This multidimensional array needs to be sorted by hour, ascending. The problem is, I don't know how to sort an multidimensional array. The first dimension (0, 1 and 2), needs to be changed, according to the hour, but all other details from dimension 2 (teacher, group etc.) also need to change from index, because otherwise the data is mixed.
You don't know how many indexes there are. In this example, the correct sequence should be: klas4[2][...], klas4[1][...], klas[0][...]

In PHP there's a certain function *multisort*, but I couldn't find this in jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: `klas4[0] = [];` should really be an object, not an array. It should look like `klas4[0] = {
"hour" : 6,
"teacher" : "JAG",
"group" : "V4B",
"subject" : "IN",
"classroom" : "B111" };`

Comment: You're using arrays improperly, when you think you're adding elements you're just adding properties to the array object. see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630471/strings-as-keys-of-array-in-javascript) for more info.

Comment: @epascarello you can omit the quotes on the keys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
klas4.sort( function(a,b){ return a.hour - b.hour } );
```

should do it.

It helps to think of klas4 not as a multi-array but as 1 array of objects.
Then you sort the objects in that array with a sort function.

The sort function takes 2 objects and you must return which one comes first.

You should read on sort() for Array, google that.

Also, as others have commented; the entries for klas4 are really objects, you should use

```
klas4[2] = {};
```

or even better

```
klas4[2] = { hour:1 , teacher:"JAG" , group:"V4A" , subject: "IN" };
```

Finally, I assume you are a native Dutch or German speaker, as I am. I would strongly suggest to name all your variables in English, `class4`, not `klas4`. It is the right, professional thing to do.